# I got some problem in python env when use GCP api key

Tags: python, google-translate

I want to use google translation api but I have some problems.

My env is Linux ubuntu 18 and python with Atom idle

I was used gcloud to set my configuration and got auth login, auth login token.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=//api_key.json
gcloud init
gcloud auth application-default login
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

so I could use curl and got some test data

```
curl -X POST      -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)      -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"      --data 
"{
  'q': 'Hello world',
  'q': 'My name is Jeff',
  'target': 'de'
}" "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Hallo Welt",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "Mein Name ist Jeff",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run test code in Atom idle, my project number is wrong. 
It is my past project.
Even I run test code in bash python, it is same situation

I dont know what is wrong, I just guess some problem in python env.

raised error

```
raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST 
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2: Cloud Translation    
API has not been used in project [wrong number] before or it is disabled.   
Enable it by visiting
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com
/overview?project=[wrong number] then retry. If you enabled this API 
recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and 
retry.
```

Comment: If you suspect there's a problem in your code, you should post the relevant part of that code. However, please keep in mind that *"why isn't this code working?"* is an off-topic question on Stack Overflow (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for details)

Answer (score 0):

This error message is usually thrown when the application is not being **authenticated** correctly due to several reasons such as missing files, invalid credential paths, incorrect environment variables assignations, among other causes. Since the Client Libraries need to pull the credentials data from the environment variable or the client object, it is required to ensure you are pointing to the correct authentication files. Keep in mind this issue might not occur when using `CURL` command because you were passing the `access-token` directly.

Based on this, I recommend you to confirm that you are using the JSON file credentials of your current project, as well as follow the [Obtaining and providing service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) guide in order to **explicitly specify your service account file** directly into your code; In this way, you will be able to set it permanently and verify if you are passing the service credentials correctly. Additionally, you can take a look on [Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) guide that contains the step-by-step process required to use the Translation API with Python.

**Passing the path to the service account key in code example:**

```
def explicit():
from google.cloud import storage

# Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
# file.
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')

# Make an authenticated API request
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)
```